# Green function for $(-\Delta)^s + Id$ operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, nonlinear-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Does anyone know, how to find the Green function for the sum of fractional Laplacian and identity operator ($:= (-\Delta)^s + Id $) in unbounded domain (in $\mathbb{R}^N$) where $s \in (0,1)$?

Comment: I guess $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $-\Delta$ is the self-adjoint realization o fthe Laplacian. What is your background in analysis of PDEs? Do you know the formula without the identity operator? What is your goal? Would a formula using pseudo-differential calculus be satisfying?

Comment: Here $s \in (0,1)$ and the operator is fractional Laplacian (can be defined in both principal value sense or by Fourier transform). There is one paper of C. Bucur (CPAA-2016) where the results is provided for the fractional Laplacian (without the identity operator). I was interested in the question, if I add the identity operator what could be possible change in the Green function (they have some application in studying in Schrodinger type equations)?

Comment: formula via the pseudo differential calculus could be starting point to explore the question..

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$, you can just take the Fourier transform ... but even WolframAlpha does not seems to know $\mathcal F( 1/(1+|x|^{1/2}) )$ and $\mathcal F( 1/(1+|x|) )$ for the cases $s=1/4$ and $s=1/2$ for example.